# Установка Pecl Libevent

Tags: php, ubuntu, pecl, libevent

Приветствую!
Не получается установить pecl libevent.
В phpinfo "20-libevent.ini" отображается, но при вызове функции event_base_new() - ошибка: *Call to undefined function*

*pecl list* не отображает libevent, при попытке установить через команду *pecl install libevent-beta* или *pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.0.4* - ошибка:

> pecl/event conflicts with package "pecl/libevent" (version >= 0.0.2),
>   downloaded version is 0.1.0 pecl/libevent cannot be installed,
>   conflicts with installed packages No valid packages found install
>   failed

Что нужно сделать, чтобы все нормально заработало? (Ubuntu 16)

UPD:
После удаления event: *pecl ununstall event* при попытке установить libevent возникает другая ошибка:

> pecl/libevent requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 6.0.0,
>   excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is
>   7.0.10-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 No valid packages found

При том, что активирован php 5.6

UPD:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20131226/libevent.so' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20131226/libevent.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_sockets_le_socket in Unknown on line 0

UPD:
Решил проблему следующим образом: файлы 20-libevent.ini переименовал в 20-x-libevent.ini, но теперь не получается установить библиотеку event, выходит ошибка:

> *pecl install event*
>
> pecl/event conflicts with package "pecl/libevent" (version >= 0.0.2), installed version is 0.1.0 pecl/event conflicts
>   with PHP extension "libevent"

Comment: `php -v` и `php -m` что выдают?

Comment: php -v: PHP 7.0.10-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS ) , phpinfo(): PHP Version 5.6.25-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, в php -m нету libevent, не смотря на то,что только что смог установить его с помощью команды *pecl install --ignore-errors libevent-beta*, выходит та же ошибка *Call to undefined function*

Comment: Переключите CLI версию на 5.6. Получается что вы устанавливаете для версии 5.6 из под версии 7. Скорее всего с конфигом не той версии  работаете

Comment: Переключил cli версию, теперь при вводе команды *pecl list* появляется множество непонятных Notice и Warning

Comment: Предположительно что конфиги отличаются и для 5.6 включен error_reporting E_ALL

Comment: Что нужно исправить в данном случае? *error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT*

Comment: Ну формулировка "Непонятные ошибки" как понимаете не сильно информативна. Найти **php.ini** `locate php.ini` и посмотреть/поменять там **error_reporting** на **E_ERROR**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44531/discussion-between-ninazu-and-cript).

Comment: Данную проблему смог устранить с помощью команды *sudo apt-get install php-xml php5.6-xml*, но с Libevent все по прежнему

Comment: переустановил расширение pecl uninstall libevent - pecl install libevent-beta, теперь вознкиает такая ошибка
*PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/libevent.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/libevent.so: undefined symbol: php_sockets_le_socket in Unknown on line 0*